# Create 3DES Encrypted string using C# Compatible dbms_obfuscation_toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, obfuscation

I am trying to understand and implement 3DES Encryption using C# that would be compatible with oracle dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.

I got help from below two location

> https://javasight.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/net-encryption-and-oracle-decryption/
>
> [Different DES Encryption in Oracle and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693331/different-des-encryption-in-oracle-and-net)

Unfortunately I'm unable to create an encrypted string compatible with below statement

```
select trim(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESDecrypt(input_string=>utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('EncryptedString')),key_string=>'MagicKey'))
```

from dual

```
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
{
    byte[] keyArray;
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);


    string iv = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    string s = "4D616769634B6579";
    keyArray = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[iv.Length];
    ivBytes = StringUtilities.HexStringToByteArray(iv);


    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    tdes.IV = ivBytes;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock
            (toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    tdes.Clear();
    return StringUtilities.ByteArrayToHexString(resultArray);
}
```

The key that I am using in C# Code is `rawtohex('MagicKey')` which translates to 4D616769634B6579